# How to make tabel view as a content ( book) reader

Tags: iphone

I have a 4 cell in a tableview coming data from the SQLlite data base .

Now I want to have UITable view  as a book reader means if any buddy swipe it, next 4 elements come into the Table view and when reverse back is goes back to previous data .

The data is has fixed 4 cells .

Also how to make transitions in the table view .

Please help me with any code do you have struggling from many days

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how you wold to the transition to the other "page" maybe with a navigationController. It's meant to do that.

To catch the swipe event on a tableview you have to set the controller as Delegate of you table view then implement this method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle
```

forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

In this method you will have to push the next view to you're navigation controller

If you dont want the "Delete button" to appear, which is you case i think you have to implement this second method :

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

If this solution doesn't work, a little workdaround would be a add a transparent subview above your table view and to catch, touches event on this view.

Answer (score 0):

Not getting how to implement that , also how to make table view work as a paging concept

Like example first page appear text as

**Main content**

**sub tittle 1**

**sub tittle1 2**

**sub tittle 3**

Now swipes provide next data to be displayed same as above

**Main content**

**sub tittle 1**

**sub tittle1 2**

**sub tittle 3**